# iTextPDF Signature: how to not show signature fields, but show an image

Tags: java, itext, sign, pdfstamper

I use itextpdf-5 for signing on PDF. I would like to sign the document, but to make invisible all the fields  (reason, location) except the image. I can do this in a third-party program (I attach an example of such a PDF: the signature stores all the data, but does not display).
I did not find anything like this in the documentation to do so in my program (I am enclosing code example)

[Example PDF with hide data](https://yadi.sk/i/XoI8zVB4nlfJPw)

```
 private static void emptySignature(String src, String dest, String sigName, int page, int x, int y) {
    try {
        Image image = Image.getInstance(new File(currentPatient.getCurrentSign().getLocalFilePath()).toURL());;
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader,os,'\0',new File("data/results/temp"),true);

        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(x,y,x+80,y-60),page,sigName); 
        //Hide it!
        appearance.setReason("Nikita");
        appearance.setLocation("Sanitas");
        //No hide
        appearance.setImage(image);

        ExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance,external,8192);
        os.close();
        reader.close();
        stamper.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PdfSignatureAppearance` has a setter `setRenderingMode` with a `RenderingMode` parameter.
`RenderingMode` is an enumeration with these values:

```
public enum RenderingMode {
    /**
     * The rendering mode is just the description.
     */
    DESCRIPTION,
    /**
     * The rendering mode is the name of the signer and the description.
     */
    NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION,
    /**
     * The rendering mode is an image and the description.
     */
    GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION,
    /**
     * The rendering mode is just an image.
     */
    GRAPHIC
}
```

*To make invisible all the fields (reason, location) except the image,* therefore, simply set the rendering mode to `GRAPHIC`:

```
appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
```